# How do I copy and paste multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to paste `width` and `length` from Document A to Document B. I only need the value. At the moment I use Paste Special but I have to do it one by one.

How can I copy all of them at once?

[image]

Comment: DONT SHOUT!
There's no simple way of doing this. Try to access each cell with an `INDIRECT` or `OFFSET` formula!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be achieved, eg for D42, with `=VLOOKUP($A42,SourceSheet!$A:$C,2,0)` (change `,2,` to `,3,` for E42), then filter B to select non-blanks and copy the formulae to suit.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following formula in D42:

```
=OFFSET(SourceSheet!$B$1,ROW()/3-1,COLUMN()-4)
```

(replace SourceSheet with your sheet name).

Then, copy this formula to all the blue cells. Paste a value copy, if required...

Comment: Is there a way to copy and paste this code too all the cells at once?

Comment: even though that works, I can't use it. I cant have the formula in my file. any other way of solving this problem without the use of formulas?

Comment: yeah its temporary. as long as at the end of the day the value in the cell is a number and not a formula. document A will be removed after the data is transferred. is there a way to do this?

Comment: how do you paste a value copy?